# Creating a plain tabbing functionality with plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to know how to create a tabbing functionality like the one provided by jQuery UI in plain JavaScript. I really don't know how is it done because the main reason being that I can't get my head around it!

So, what basically I need help regarding is the logic by which I would be able to create the feature.

Some things I can't get my head around are like, how does the tabs once clicked shift styles from one element(tab) to another? How does the previous tab lose its style while other getting the same styles? I know they are actually switching `classes` but how?

Similarly how does a list show when one tab is clicked, and it hides and another one shows when another tab is clicked. I can't really get the logic behind the shifting of styles.

Comment: Is there some reason you don't want to use jQueryUi for this?  I'm not sure why you want to re-invent the wheel on this one.  There are plenty of other javascript libraries that provide similar functionality, as well.  Bootstrap, YUI, and others.

Comment: @Matt I just want to have fun learning new stuff! Moreover, I can't go on learning libraries if I don't know what's going on behind the scenes, can I?

Comment: @akash4eva See, that's why I browsed jQuery's development code. It drastically improved my knowledge... John Resig was my teacher. Kinda. He didn't even know.

Comment: Basically, you code a click handler  and assign it to  each tab, it removes the "selectedTab" class from all other tabs, and adds the "selectedTab" class to the one that was clicked. The "selectedTab" class has the CSS to give the appearance you want. The click handler hides all divs/sections for the other tabs and shows the one associated with the clicked on.

Comment: @jalynn2 good answer you should probably have posted it as such ;-)

Comment: @jalynn2 So, that's it basically? Looping through all the elements and removing or adding classes? That's what I've thought long ago! Damn, isn't there any better and easier way around the logic!

Comment: @akash4eva: That's the magic of JQuery -- all that looping is reduced to a few lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

DynamicDrive has an example. Does this help?

[DynamicDrive Tab Tutorial](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/tabcontent_suppliment.htm)

Comment: This seems useful. Thanks BTW @Tim

Comment: this is effectively another library like jquery ui, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I would do:

1. Look at the instructions for jQueryUi's tab control (or DynamicDrive or YUI or Bootstrap or whatever).
2. Observe how the HTML for these containers is constructed.
3. Replicate this HTML structure on your page
4. Find W3C or Mozilla's documentation on creating event handlers with javascript, add "onClick" to the tab elements in your HTML, either dynamically, or via the "onclick" html attribute
5. Find W3C or other documentation on how to manipulate the style or class attributes of an HTML element using javascript, apply this to your tabs with the onclick event.

If you want to get more fancy there is literally a ton of documentation on javascript out there.